# Safari mobile browser doesn't have selectedOptions for <select>

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I am working on a web app and was testing it on my ipad when I realized that something was not working.

I decided to further look into it and discovered that this won't work on the ipad but will on desktop browser:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function(e) {
        console.log(e.srcElement.selectedOptions);                
    });
});​
```

Ipad console shows `undefined`

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSdwU/) to test it out with.

Is my approach wrong? Or is this a bug in mobile safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to be using e.srcElement.selectedIndex or e.srcElement.value?

```
e.srcElement.options[e.srcElement.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sort");
```

Comment: I need to be able to get ahold of the `<option data-sort="name">` to get attributes off of it e.g. data-sort

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mSdwU/12/
e.srcElement.options[e.srcElement.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sort");